# bootstrap.min.css "Generated source files should not be edited" Problem

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, pycharm

I am new to bootstrap when I try to create bootstrap.min.css file, it says "Generated source files should not be edited" and I can not edit. How can I solve this problem ? Thank you.

Comment: You're going to have elaborate on this more. How did you install bootstrap? What framework are you building within that includes bootstrap, ect.

If you're using bootstrap with Sass you can read how to customize/modify bootstrap here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/customize/overview/

The *.min.css files are the compiled and minified versions of the main repository to speed up loading.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.